# The Rust Programming Language Pig Latin

Tags: strings, rust, pig-latin

This is my implementation of the Pig Latin recommended exercise in The Rust Programming Language book. Any pointers on making this code more idiomatic or run more optimal?

```rust
fn pig_latin() {
    let s = String::from("Some abobus string 32 text привет абоба 123");
    let mut new_s = s.clone();

    let consonant = Vec::from([
        'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r',
        's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'й',
        'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ'
    ]);  //  Согласные

    for word in s.split_whitespace() {

        let chars = word.chars();
        if let Some(ch) = chars.peekable().peek() {
            if ch.is_alphabetic() {
                if consonant.contains(ch.to_lowercase().peekable().peek().map_or(ch, |v| v )) {
                    new_s = new_s.replace(word, &format!("{}-{}ay", &word[ch.len_utf8()..word.len()], ch));
                } else {
                    new_s = new_s.replace(word, &format!("{}-hay", &word[0..word.len()]));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    println!("Old: '{}' \nNew: '{}'", s, new_s);
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

```
let consonant = Vec::from([
    'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r',
    's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'й',
    'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ'
]);
```

An alternative would be:

```
fn is_consonant(character: char) -> bool {
   matches!(character, 'b' | 'c' | ...)
}
```

My theory would be that Rust probably generated somewhat better code against a pattern match as compared to searching a vector.

```
    let chars = word.chars();
    if let Some(ch) = chars.peekable().peek() {
```

There doesn't seem to be any reason to use peekable here. Just use `word.chars.next()`.

```
     if consonant.contains(ch.to_lowercase().peekable().peek().map_or(ch, |v| v )) {
```

You don't need peekable here either. I would also probably not use `map_or` but instead `unwrap`. My theory would be that `to_lowercase` is never going to return an empty string, so `next` or `peek` should always return something. If it doesn't, I don't think falling back to `ch` makes sense.

```
                new_s = new_s.replace(word, &format!("{}-{}ay", &word[ch.len_utf8()..word.len()], ch));
```

This is wrong. You replace the whole string, but its very possible that the word appears other places in the string and will give you odd results.